# Understanding go composite literal

Tags: go, composite-literals

Why a function value assignment to **f** is not a composite literal?

Go lang specification [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) says below, hence function value cannot be constructed with composite Literal.

> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated

However, the function value assignment to **f** in the code looks as a composite literal expression for type **func() int**.

Is there a reason function object cannot be constructed as a composite literal?

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    var x int = 0

    var f func() int
    f = func() int{ x++; return x * x }  // <---- Why this cannot be a composite literal?

    fmt.Println(f())   // 1
    fmt.Println(f())   // 4
    fmt.Println(f())   // 9

    // Define a type for "func() int" type 
    type SQUARE func() int
    g := SQUARE{ x++; return x * x}   // <--- Error with Invalid composite literal type: SQUARE 

    fmt.Println(g())
}
```

Comment: Function assignment doesn't look like a composite literal. Composite literal is a list of comma-separated keyed elements surrounded with curly braces. The fact that function syntax also use curly braces doesn't make it look like a composite literal.

Answer (score 7):

### Does `f = func() int{ x++; return x * x }` looks like composite literal?

Not really)

As [spec states](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and maps... They consist of the type of the literal followed by a brace-bound list of elements.

To make this statement clearer, here is production rule for composite literal:

```
CompositeLit  = LiteralType LiteralValue .
```

You can see, that production rule for [`LiteralValue`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#LiteralValue) is:

```
LiteralValue  = "{" [ ElementList [ "," ] ] "}" .
```

and [`FunctionBody`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#FunctionBody), doesn't look at all like this. Basically, it's list of `Statement`'s:

```
FunctionBody = Block .
Block = "{" StatementList "}" .
StatementList = { Statement ";" } .
```

### Why function cannot be constructed as a composite literal?

I wasn't able to find any documented answer to that, but simplest assumption would be that main reasons are:

- Avoid confusion. Here is example, if it would be allowed to construct composite literal for function:

```
type SquareFunc func() int

type Square struct {
    Function SquareFunc
}

func main() {
    f := SquareFunc{ return 1 }
    s := Square{ buildSquareFunc() }
}
```

`s:= ...` line(which is supposed to be composite type) could be easily confused with 1st line.

- Besides body, function has one more important thing -- [`Signature`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Signature). If you could construct composite literal for function, how would you define it's arguments and return parameters names? You could define names in type definition -- but that would cause inflexibility(sometimes you want to use different parameter names) and code like:

```
type SquareFunc func(int x) int

func main() {
    x := 1

    f := SquareFunc{ 
        x++
        return x * x
    }
    f(2)
}
```

would look too unclear, as it wouldn't be obvious what `x` variable does it actually use.

Comment: "I wasn't able to find any documented answer to that". Here you go: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30931. You get into trouble when you consider arguments and named return values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format it.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main(){
   var x int = 0

   var f func() int
   f = (func() int{ x++; return x * x })  // <---- Why this cannot be a composite literal?

   fmt.Println(f())   // 1
   fmt.Println(f())   // 4
   fmt.Println(f())   // 9

   // Define a type for "func() int" type 
   type SQUARE func() int
   g := SQUARE(func()int{ x++; return x * x})   // <--- Error with Invalid composite literal type: SQUARE 

   fmt.Println(g())
}
```

Wrap your variable `f` using `()`.
In the case of `SQUARE`, you need to write the `func() int` before starting your function code