# Go - building POST body, receive error "invalid composite literal type string"

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a POST body in Go, but I keep getting the following error:

***invalid composite literal type string***

Snippets of my code and structs are below, I'm can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
postData := projectPostData{
    Filters: projectFilters{
        Name: string{ // <-- Error is referred to on this line 
            target,
        },
    },
}

type projectPostData struct {
    Filters projectFilters `json:"filters,omitempty"`
}

type projectFilters struct {
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting `string { target }` to do? If you are just trying to make a `string` value you can just cast it to a string if its not already one: `string(target)`

Comment: `target` contains the string value I've passed into the function. I've changed it to the following, but I get the same error: ...`Name: { string(target), }`...

Comment: If `target` is already a string you need no '{ ... }', try again with `Name: target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the below code:

```
package main 

import(
    "fmt"
)


type projectFilters struct {
    Name string `json:"string,omitempty"`
}

type projectPostData struct {
    Filters projectFilters `json:"filters,omitempty"`
}



func main(){
    target := "test target"

    postData := projectPostData{
        Filters: projectFilters{
            Name: target,
        },
    }
    
    fmt.Println(postData)
}
```

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440004/understanding-go-composite-literal to further want to know.